# Selecting Random rows with limit in SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, random

I have went through many related threads and i was not successful yet .

I dont know where i am going wrong , i have the following method to get the rows .

```
    public Cursor getallrows (String fid , String sid , String bid , String pid , String limit)
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_ALLPENLIST, new String[] {"rowpos","Peninnerid","issampled","onesymbol","twosymbol","threesymbol","foursymbol","fivesymbol","buildingid","farmid","sampleid","penid"}, "farmid = "+fid+" and sampleid = "+sid+" and buildingid = "+bid+" and penid = "+pid , null, null, null,"RANDOM()",limit);
    }
```

but the above method returns me the correct number of rows mentioned in the limit but not in the Random order , it is returning the first n rows mentioned in the limit variable .

Is this `RANDOM()` case-sensitive ? But i have also tried with `Random()` and `"RANDOM() LIMIT "+limit` in the place of 7th parameter .

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: what type of object is `limit` (int, string, etc)?

Comment: it is String , i have passed as the parameter to the method in the code , please refer .

Comment: Did my answer not work for you with the explicit string of `1`?

Comment: No i have tried but it is returning only the first row .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work with return random rows based off if the `limit` variable is of string type or you can be explicit with it like this:

```
db.query(DATABASE_ALLPENLIST, 
         new String[] {"rowpos","Peninnerid","issampled","onesymbol","twosymbol","threesymbol","foursymbol","fivesymbol","buildingid","farmid","sampleid","penid"}, 
         "farmid = "+fid+" and sampleid = "+sid+" and buildingid = "+bid+" and penid = "+pid ,
         null, 
         null, 
         null,
         "RANDOM()",
         "1");
```

or try raw query:

```
db.rawQuery("Select rowpos, Peninnerid , issampled, onesymbol, twosymbol, threesymbol, foursymbol, fivesymbol, buildingid, farmid, sampleid, penid From " + DATABASE_ALLPENLIST + " Order By RANDOM() LIMIT ?", new String[] {limit});
```

Doumentation to this API: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: but i want to pass the limit dynamically , i mean i have some calculation to find the limit . So i could not give as "1" . Please advice .

Comment: I know it is a dumb question but I have to ask, do you have more than one row in your table?

Comment: @VIGNESH Can you try the rawQuery that I posted and see if it is doing the same thing to you?

Comment: but it requires API level of 16 (i.e) Jelly bean .

Comment: Wait, rawQuery does not require API 16, it was added in API 1

Comment: Yes . And i have tested db.rawQuery("Select rowpos, Peninnerid , issampled, onesymbol, twosymbol, threesymbol, foursymbol, fivesymbol, buildingid, farmid, sampleid, penid From " + DATABASE_ALLPENLIST + " Order By RANDOM() LIMIT "+limit , null);    but that didnt work .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33821/discussion-between-vignesh-and-obiemd5)